# Is R IGraph computing undirected shortest path in directed network?

Tags: r, igraph

there is something that i'm missing about IGraph shortest paths computation.

suppose I generate a network (find somewhere in stackoverflow) and perform simple computations:

```
library(igraph);
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David", "David", "Esmeralda"), to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"));
g = simplify(graph_from_data_frame(d=relations, directed=T), remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T);
#plotting the network in order to appreciate the directions of the edges
plot(g,edge.arrow.size=0.5);
#V(g)[5] is "Alice" which apparently should not be able to reach any node
print(all_shortest_paths(g,from=V(g)[5],to=V(g),mode="all")$res);
```

as you can see, the shortest paths found are:

```
> print(all_shortest_paths(g,from=V(g)[5],to=V(g),mode="all")$res);
[[1]]
+ 2/5 vertices, named, from 823c15d:
[1] Alice Bob  

[[2]]
+ 2/5 vertices, named, from 823c15d:
[1] Alice Cecil

[[3]]
+ 2/5 vertices, named, from 823c15d:
[1] Alice David

[[4]]
+ 2/5 vertices, named, from 823c15d:
[1] Alice     Esmeralda

[[5]]
+ 1/5 vertex, named, from 823c15d:
[1] Alice
```

what I'm expecting is that no shortest paths should be returned since Alice, in a directed graph, has no edges that are going out from itself.
Is this due to the fact that, when I compute the shortest paths, I'm using the option:

```
mode="all"
```

and this, somehow, works even for directed graphs?

Of course, if I change the graph construction and set:

```
directed=F
```

i.e.

```
library(igraph);
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David", "David", "Esmeralda"), to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"));

g = simplify(graph_from_data_frame(d=relations, directed=F), remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T);

#plottin the network in order to appreciate the directions of the edges
plot(g,edge.arrow.size=0.5);

#V(g)[5] is "Alice" which apparently should not be able to reach any node
print(all_shortest_paths(g,from=V(g)[5],to=V(g),mode="all")$res);
```

the same results are returned.

What is going on? Am I just too tired to get this straight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just what `mode="all"` means - use all edges regardless of direction.

I will use a simpler graph to make it easy to see what is going on.

```
rel2 <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Bob", "David"), 
        to=c("Alice", "Carol", "Carol"))
g = simplify(graph_from_data_frame(d=rel2, directed=T))
LO = layout_as_bipartite(g, types=c(F,F,T,T))
plot(g, layout=LO)
```

[image: Simple directional graph]

Now with your shortest path statement

```
print(all_shortest_paths(g,from=V(g)[3],to=V(g),mode="all")$res)
[[1]]
+ 2/4 vertices, named:
[1] Alice Bob  
[[2]]
+ 4/4 vertices, named:
[1] Alice Bob   Carol David
[[3]]
+ 1/4 vertex, named:
[1] Alice
[[4]]
+ 3/4 vertices, named:
[1] Alice Bob   Carol
```

We get all paths connecting Alice to another node, even though the edges go in opposite directions.

I think that what you want is:

```
print(all_shortest_paths(g,from=V(g)[3],to=V(g),mode="out")$res)
[[1]]
+ 1/4 vertex, named:
```

Which gives only the zero-length path from Alice to itself.

Just for completeness,

```
print(all_shortest_paths(g,from=V(g)[3],to=V(g),mode="in")$res)
[[1]]
+ 2/4 vertices, named:
[1] Alice Bob  

[[2]]
+ 1/4 vertex, named:
[1] Alice
```

This follows paths using only incoming edges, so we get the path "from" Alice "to" Bob using the edge into Alice,  but we get nothing else because there are no edges into Bob.

Comment: ok, so if a use `mode="all"` then it does not matter whether my graph was declared as directed or undirected. That was the answer I was looking for.
It's still weird, to me, to define a function that does something which, from the graph perspective, should not be allowed but...that's it!

Comment: Yes. I think that the view here is that if you want to use directed paths, you must use either `mode="in"` or `mode="out"`.  "all" is more about connectivity.

Comment: may I ask what do you mean when you say that **"all" is more about connectivity**?

Comment: Yes.  When you use "all" edges,  you get paths to anything that is connected to the node (by paths irrespective of direction). This will report shortest paths between all pairs of nodes in the same connected component.